# Python and Telethon Error invalidpeer while sending messages to telegram channel

Tags: python, telethon

I have tried adding a few suggestions to fix this and all the solution i have tried have            created a #new error saying messages cant be sent white disconnected. Strangely enough i have another python program that runs off of similar code concurrently with no problem at all. However, this program stopped working a few months ago.

#Error:

```
   C:\Users\main4_cocogroups>main.py --link https://www.instagram.com/reel/
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\main4_cocogroups\main.py", line 82, in <module>
       client.send_message(entity=entity, message="Dx24 " + args.ig_link, link_preview=False)
     File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\sync.py", line 39, in syncified
        return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
     File "C:\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
        return future.result()
     File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\messages.py", line 872, in send_message
        result = await self(request)
     File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in __call__
       return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
     File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 84, in _call
       result = await future
   telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.PeerIdInvalidError: An invalid Peer was used. Make sure to pass the right peer type and that the value is valid (for instance, bots cannot start conversations) (caused    by SendMessageRequest)
```

#Program code:

```
import argparse
import time
import os.path


from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-l', '--link', dest='ig_link', type=str, required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()


##
# @brief The function returns the last time when messages were sent.
# @return The Unix time is returned.
def get_last_action():
    # Create the file if needed.
        if not os.path.isfile('interval.txt'):
        f = open("interval.txt", "w")
        f.close()

    file1 = open("interval.txt", "r")
    result = file1.readline()
    file1.close()

    if result.isnumeric():
        return int(result)
    else:
        return 0


# Login
phone = "my phone"
api_id = my api
api_hash = "my hash"

client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()

if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.start()
    
# Set the interval between iterations in seconds.
interval = 1000

while True:
    if int(time.time()) > (get_last_action() + interval):
    
       # Coco S&L Dx30
       group = "https://t.me/Cocochicclubdx30LS"
       entity = client.get_input_entity(group)
       client.send_message(entity=entity, message="Dx30 " + args.ig_link, link_preview=False)


       # Update the value when the last iteration was triggered.
       file = open("interval.txt", "w")
       file.write(str(int(time.time())))
       file.close()
```

Comment: I have tried adding a few suggestions to fix this and all the solution i have tried have            created a #new error saying messages cant be sent white disconnected. Strangely enough i have another python program that runs off of similar code concurrently with no problem at all. However, this program stopped working a few months ago.

Comment: The username may be in cache, and causing it to load the wrong channel. Try using `get_entity` instead of `get_input_entity`. Beware this has higher floodwaits. You should generally use the channel ID, not its username, which is less reliable.

Comment: @Lonami Where would i make the suggested change for the channel ID you suggested. I dont see in my code where that is even specified. since i updated to the get_entity command it is working again! But i would still like to make it the best I can. Additionally I am currently having to run 2 instances of this program to accomplish firing messages for different intervals. is there a way to combine them so i only have to run one instance?

Comment: @Lonami I stying to updated the channgel ID but I am not sure where i make the update you sugested. I have started to receive some errors.